# PyCharm TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

Very new to Python 3.  Teaching myself via books and the web.

Currently using Python 3.6 and PyCharm 2016.3.2

Have a small program that PyCharm says is syntactically fine (green check mark)
but when I run it I get this error:

```
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

for line 9 of my code.  I have looked up the error but I am not seeing where in my program I am committing this error.  Can somebody please point out where my error lies?

```
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # This is the      line that PyCharm flags as causing the problem.
```

Thank you.

```
import socket
import os

user_url = input("Enter url: ")
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    host_name = user_url.split("/")[2]
    mysock.connect((host_name, 80))
    mysock.send('GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n')
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a valid URL")
    os.sys.exit(1)

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data)

mysock.close()
```

Comment: My bad.  I flagged the wrong line.

Comment: This is the line that PyCharm says is bad:  mysock.send('GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n')

Comment: Might want to change it to mysock.sendall  instead of mysock.send to ensure all the messages is sent

Comment: I figured it out:

Comment: import socket
import os

user_url = input("Enter url: ")
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
message = ('GET ' + user_url + ' HTTP/1.0\n\n')
message2 = b'message'
try:
 host_name = user_url.split("/")[2]
 mysock.connect((host_name, 80))
 mysock.sendall(message2)
except ValueError:
 print("Please enter a valid URL")
 os.sys.exit(1)

while True:
 data = mysock.recv(512)
 if len(data) < 1:
  break
 print(data)

mysock.close()

Comment: yeah, like i said, SendALL not Send... glad you got it working :)